# How to read or access userState in MS Bot Framework V4?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I have defined a property 'UserProfile' in the parent dialog called  UserProfileDialog as shown below

```
class UserProfileDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(userState) {
        super(USER_PROFILE_DIALOG);

        this.userProfile = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE);
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(NAME_PROMPT)); ...
      }
      async nameStep(step) {
        const userProfile = await this.userProfile.get(step.context, new UserProfile());
        userProfile.isLoggedIn = false;
        return await step.beginDialog(LOGIN_DIALOG);
        }
    }
}
```

From the parent dialog I am calling a child dialog called the LOGIN_DIALOG

```
class LoginDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(userState) {
        super(LOGIN_DIALOG);
        this.userProfile = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE);
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));

        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.initialStep.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    async initialStep(stepContext) {
        const userProfile = await this.userProfile.get(stepContext.context, new UserProfile());
     }
}
```

**Problem:** I want to access the UserProfile property defined in the UserProflieDialog from the LoginDialog.
But I get the following error
"uncaughtException: userState.createProperty is not a function

How to resolve this error and access the userState property defined elsewhere from the current dialog?

Comment: how do you pass userState to the LoginDialog? There should be something like '        this.addDialog(new LoginDialog(userState)) ' in your UserProfileDialog's constructor.

Comment: do you still need help? Are you following any specific sample?